# Hack to convert javascript number to UInt32

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword, indexof, uint32

**Edit:** This question is out of date as the Polyfill example has been updated. I'm leaving the question here just for reference. Read the correct answer for useful information on bitwise shift operators.

---

**Question:**

On line 7 in the Polyfill example of the Mozilla [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) page they comment this:

```
var length = this.length >>> 0; // Hack to convert object.length to a UInt32
```

But the [bitwise shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Bitwise_operators) specification on Mozilla clearly states that the operator returns a value of the same type as the left operand:

> Shift operators convert their operands to thirty-two-bit integers and return a result of the same type as the left operand.

So shouldn't length receive the standard 64-bit float value? Or can someone point out to me where the hack starts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The ECMAScript specification states that the value is converted to UInt32 in step 5 and 8 of http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7:

> ## 11.7.3 The Unsigned Right Shift Operator ( >>> )
>
> Performs a zero-filling bitwise right shift operation on the left operand by the amount > specified by the right operand.
>
> The production `ShiftExpression : ShiftExpression >>> AdditiveExpression` is evaluated as  follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `ShiftExpression`.
> 2. Let `lval` be `GetValue(lref)`.
> 3. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `AdditiveExpression`.
> 4. Let `rval` be `GetValue(rref)`.
> 5. **Let `lnum` be `ToUint32(lval)`**.
> 6. Let `rnum` be `ToUint32(rval)`.
> 7. Let `shiftCount` be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of `rnum`, that is, compute `rnum & 0x1F`.
> 8. Return the result of performing a zero-filling right shift of `lnum` by `shiftCount` bits. Vacated bits are filled with zero. **The result is an unsigned 32-bit integer**.

Comment: Thanks for the lookup and points for referencing the spec. That also means that the Mozilla reference guide linked in my post is wrong about bitwise operators.

Comment: TLDR; `var uint32 = num >>> 0`

Answer (score 2):

The result is, indeed, converted back to a number, i.e., a 64-bit precision floating point number. However, before it is converted back, both operands are converted to `UInt32`, then the right shift operation is performed. This is specified in ECMAScript here:
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.7.3

The net result of `length >>> 0` is therefore, because `>>> 0` itself is a no-op, to convert `length` to a `UInt32` then back to a double. What is it good for? It forces the loss of precision, and effectively forces the value to be 1) and integer and 2) in the range [0, 2^32-1]. For example, if it was -1, it will become 2^32-1 == 4294967295. If it was, 3.6, it will become 3.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking. I think they are indeed using it as a shortcut to drop precision to an integer. But I still don't understand why they'd include such a hack. I'm assuming there's something more for the moment (smart guys at Mozilla)

Comment: Maybe something related to unicode characters? That could be a check to make sure that the number becomes a valid unicode point.

Answer (score 1):

If you run this test, Math.floor will do the same. Those hacks should be avoided if you want to understand your own code in a month or so.

```
var a=3.6, b = a >>> 0;
console.log(b);
console.log(Math.floor(a));
```

Comment: If you look at the specification of Math.floor ( http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.9 ) and compare it with Bitwise shift operator, you can see that Math.floor doesn't involve changing the internal representation of the number value from 64-bit floating point to singed or unsigned 32-bit integer representation. If it's losing precision beyond the decimal point you're going for, then you misread the question.