# Array.prototype.forEach() - why code of that method owns bitwise shift operator?

Tags: javascript, foreach, bit-shift

I am analysing native JavaScript method `Array.prototype.forEach()` code. I got it from [MDN polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) based on original [ES5](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18). I encountered such expression, which purpose of usage in that point I don't understand:

```
// 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get() internal
// method of O with the argument "length".
// 3. Let len be toUint32(lenValue).
var len = O.length >>> 0;
```

I took polyfill `forEach` from MDN, added a few `console.log()` to check what is going on there and swapped it for native `forEach()`. My conclusion is, that I don't know purpose of applying there such bitwise shift.
A piece of code, which I am using to debug this:

```
console.log( 'O: ', O, ' /this: ', this );
var len = O.length >>> 0;
console.log( 'len: ', len, ' /len === O.length: ', len === O.length, ' /len == O.length: ', len == O.length );
```

I create some array, on which I invoke "prepared' `forEach` method and I don't understand the difference between variable `len` and property `O.length`:

```
[1,3,5].forEach( elem => { console.log( 'elem: ', elem ); } )
// O:  [1, 3, 5]  /this:  [1, 3, 5]
// len:  3  /len === O.length:  true  /len == O.length:  true
// elem:  1
// elem:  3
// elem:  5
```

That array contains 3 elements and variable `len`, which has result of bitwise shift, express that value too.

I also wrote something like that:

```
3 >>> 0
// 3
```

The result of bitwise shift is exact as length of array. Moreover, the comparison between double and triple compare operator `==` / `===` yields `true`. Array length can neither be negative nor fraction number. So what is the point of using bitwise shift in native `forEach()` method code?

Comment: The comment explains the reason - the ECMAScript spec states that the value should be converted to a UInt32. This is probably a duplicate of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335853/hack-to-convert-javascript-number-to-uint32).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of reasons.

```
[].forEach.call({ length: Math.PI });

Array.from({ length: Math.sqrt(2) });
```

You don't have to know or care about them, but there are reasons.